# *ngIf sync issue with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I apologize if this is a basic question with a basic answer. I'm fairly new to Angular2 in particular and development in general, and I'm stuck.

I have a service that is pulling a list from Firebase:

```
listItems: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.listItems = af.database.list('items');
}
getFood() {
    return this.listItems;
}
```

My component:

```
list: Observable<any[]>;
delBtnActive: boolean = false;
constructor(private dataService: DataSService) {
    this.list = dataService.getFood();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.lookForDel();
}

lookForDel() {
    var found = false;
    this.list.forEach(items => {
        items.forEach(item => {
            if (item.del) {found = true};
        })
    });
    this.delBtnActive = found;
}
```

And finally my template, which makes use of the delBtnActive boolean:

```
<button *ngIf="delBtnActive">Confirm Delete</button>
```

Everything works here, except that when this route is first initialized the button does not appear on-screen when it should be there. Switching from this route to another, and then back results in the button correctly appearing. Any update to the data on Firebase will result in the button correctly appearing.

**EDIT:** Note that based on console logging, the lookForDel() method gets called OnInit. I **believe** the issue is that the ngIf is occurring before the data loads when the route is first initialized.

Any help on this specifically or tips in general would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for emitted values using `forEach`, you could compose an observable that emits a boolean - indicating whether your button should be active - each time a list is emitted from your Firebase observable:

```
delBtnActive: Observable<boolean>;

lookForDel() {
    this.delBtnActive = this.listItems.map((items) => Boolean(items.find(item => item.del));
}
```

In your template, you would then use the `async` pipe:

```
<button *ngIf="delBtnActive | async">Confirm Delete</button>
```

As to why your current implementation sometimes works and sometimes does not, the only explanation that I can see is that sometimes the `forEach` occurs synchronously and sometimes it does not. (With RxJS, that sort of thing can actually happen.)

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to comment functionality. Please note that the *only* time the code I used above does NOT work is on initial load - it works perfectly every other time. I think the Observable w/ async pipe is the way to go, but I've been thus far unable to get it to work correctly. If you know of a good tutorial on setting it up correctly, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://briantroncone.com/?p=623) one? If you want to add some [debug logging](http://staltz.com/how-to-debug-rxjs-code.html), you can put a `do` operator after the `map` and write the value to the console - to verify that the async pipe is subscribing to `delBtnActive` and that the value is what you expect.